# How to differentiate between HTML layout DWT TBB and Text layout DWT TBB for Compound Component Template

Tags: 2013-sp1, outbound-email

We are using Tridion 2013 SP1 HR1. Inside the documentation for separating HTML format and plain-text format it is not clear how to setup HTML layout DWT TBB and Text layout DWT TBB for Compound Component Template.

We are using `SetEmailType` to set `html` or `text` but while sending email it is always rendering text version of Component Presentation.

Comment: Do you have the "Set Output Item By Email Mode" TBB added?

Comment: Yes i have added this to component presentation

Comment: Soi if you have two Dreamweaver TBBs, one for plain and one for HTML then all that remains is the preference in the Contact - I assume some Contacts have the HTML preference? There are no other custom TBBs in your template that might be affecting this?

Comment: Neil my question is how the outbound email know which is plain Dreamweaver TBB or HTML Dreamweaver TBB. Should we need to specify some parameter there?

Answer (score -1):

**HTML fragment, HTML document or Plain text**
The content is rendered as raw text without further processing, and stored without any modifications.

https://docs.sdl.com/LiveContent/content/en-US/SDL%20Web-v1/GUID-23D177A4-87E1-4483-AA0A-ACF4BC25C0E2